# Bazel generate_workspace not working?

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to create my own Android app that uses TensorFlow.  I have previously built the TensorFlow Android example but that Android project is embedded inside the TensorFlow bazel project and I'd like to put my project in it's own place elsewhere on the filesystem.  So I've started down the path of using bazel to build my Android app and incorporate TensorFlow that way.

I started by looking at the bazel docs on [external dependencies](http://bazel.io/docs/external.html).  It mentions running `bazel run //src/tools/generate_workspace` to auto generate the WORKSPACE and BUILD files to include all the dependencies for all dependent bazel projects. So I ran this:

```
$ bazel run //src/tools/generate_workspace -- \
> --bazel_project=/Users/me/Dev/myAndroidProject \
> --bazel_project=/Users/me/Dev/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

I get the following output with tons of warnings about skipping transitive dependencies in tensorflow:

```
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/src/tools/generate_workspace/generate_workspace '--bazel_project=/Users/me/Dev/tensorflow/tensorflow/'
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for new_git_repository rule //external:accessibility-developer-tools yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for android_ndk_repository rule //external:androidndk yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for android_sdk_repository rule //external:androidsdk yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for new_git_repository rule //external:async yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for new_git_repository rule //external:chai yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for new_git_repository rule //external:d3 yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for new_git_repository rule //external:dagre yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for new_http_archive rule //external:eigen_archive yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for new_git_repository rule //external:es6-promise yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for new_git_repository rule //external:font-roboto yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for git_repository rule //external:gemmlowp yet, skipping
WARNING: Cannot fetch transitive dependencies for new_http_archive rule //external:gmock_archive yet, skipping
...
```

The generated WORKSPACE and BUILD files are essentially blank (only a few generated comments in each).  This obviously doesn't seem right but admittedly I don't know what I'm doing with incorporating external bazel projects as dependencies in my Android bazel project.

What have I done wrong and has anyone managed to incorporate TensorFlow into a separate Android project without jamming the Android project down inside the TensorFlow project?

Comment: I think generate_workspace have been writing only to handle maven dependencies. TensorFlow will soon have an easier way to do that.

Comment: Is it available in r08 ? The easier way implemented does not seem to work for me. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2775

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and had a look in the utility's source code. It supports only `maven_jar` WORKSPACE rule at the moment.